# SQL retrieving highest number from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL-table, containing these data:

```
idPK    groupIDFK
 1          1
 2          1
 3          2
 4          2
 5          1
```

I'm looking for a way to group the 2nd column values and display the highest value from the first column in that group. In this case, it should return these entries:

```
idPK     groupIDFK
 5          1
 4          2
```

Does my description make sense? And if so, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query where rows are sorted by groupIDFK:

```
select max(idPK) as idPK, groupIDFK from table group by groupIDFK;
```

If you need to order by idPK below is another version:

```
 select max(idPK) as idPK, groupIDFK from table group by groupIDFK order by idPK desc;
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast - and it works. I'll mark it as answered in 10 minutes, when Stackoverflow will allow me to :)